# Should I use an expression parser in my Math game?

Tags: math, expression-trees, evaluation

I'm writing some children's Math Education software for a class.

I'm going to try and present problems to students of varying skill level with randomly generated math problems of different types in fun ways.

One of the frustrations of using computer based math software is its rigidity.  If anyone has taken an online Math class, you'll know all about the frustration of taking an online quiz and having your correct answer thrown out because your problem isn't exactly formatted in their form or some weird spacing issue.

So, originally I thought, "I know!  I'll use an expression parser on the answer box so I'll be able to evaluate anything they enter and even if it isn't in the same form I'll be able to check if it is the same answer."  So I fire up my IDE and start implementing the [Shunting Yard Algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm)

This would solve the problem of it not taking fractions in the smallest form and other issues.

However, It then hit me that a tricky student would simply be able to enter most of the problems into the answer box and my expression parser would dutifully parse and evaluate it to the correct answer!

So, should I not be using an expression parser in this instance?  Do I really have to generate a single form of the answer and do a string comparison?

Comment: What a great question! Do let us know what you wind up doing -- I'm very curious.

Comment: Can you give an example of a question that would also be an answer?

Comment: @Greg: He's talking about something like: "What is the value of 500 / 2?" The "right" answer is 250, but an enterprising student can simply enter "500 / 2" in a copy-paste, and the expression evaluator will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to note how many steps your expression evaluator takes to evaluate the problem's original expression, and to compare this to the optimal answer. If there's too much difference, then the problem hasn't been reduced enough and you can suggest that the student keep going.

Don't be surprised if students come up with better answers than your own definition of "optimal", though! I was a TA/grader for several classes, and the brightest students routinely had answers on their problem sets that were superior to the ones provided by the professor.

Answer (score 2):

For simple problems where you're looking for an exact answer, then removing whitespace and doing a string compare is reasonable.

For more advanced problems, you might do the Shunting Yard Algorithm (or similar) but perhaps parametrize it so you could turn on/off reductions to guard against the tricky student. You'll notice that "simple" answers can still use the parser, but you would disable all reductions.

For example, on a division question, you'd disable the "/" reduction.

Comment: It might be hard to determine when to disable the / reduction though. For example, if the question is "1/2 + 1/4 =" the user may enter "3/4"

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

If you are writing an expression system and an evaluation/transformation/equivalence engine (isn't there one available somewhere? I am almost 100% sure that there is an open source one somewhere), then it's more of an education/algebra problem: is the student's answer algebraically closer to the original expression or to the expected expression.

I'm not sure how to answer that, but just an idea (not necessarily practical): perhaps your evaluation engine can count transformation steps to equivalence. If the answer takes less steps to the expected than it did to the original, it might be ok. If it's too close to the original, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression parser, but apply restrictions on the complexity of the expressions permitted in the answer.

For example, if the goal is to reduce (4/5)*(1/2) and you want to allow either (2/5) or (4/10), then you could restrict the set of allowable answers to expressions whose trees take the form (x/y) and which also evaluate to the correct number.  Perhaps you would also allow "0.4", i.e. expressions of the form (x) which evaluate to the correct number.

This is exactly what you would (implicitly) be doing if you graded the problem manually -- you would be looking for an answer that is correct but which also falls into an acceptable class.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing this in mathematics assessment software is to allow the question setter to specify expressions/strings that are not allowed in a correct answer.

If you happen to be interested in existing software, there's the open-source Stack http://www.stack.bham.ac.uk/ (or various commercial options such as MapleTA). I suspect most of the problems that you'll come across have also been encountered by Stack so even if you don't want to use it, it might be educational to look at how it approaches things.